# Executing ksql query using node npm ksqlDb-client throwing an timeout error

Tags: node.js, kafka-consumer-api, confluent-platform, ksqldb

Hi am trying to execute the KSQL query using npm package ksqlDb-client package, it throws an timeout error.  I have attached the code as well, please let me know any issues over there.
**when am hit this `GET` URL below method will execute https://localhost:5000/testKsql**

```
exports.getKSQLStream = async () => {
    const options = {
        authorization: {
            username: "admin",
            password: "pw",
            ssl: {
                ca:  CAs,
                crt: myClientCert,
                key: myClientKey,
            }
        },
        host:  'https://ixxxx.xcxx.net',
        timeout: 20000
    }
    const client = new KsqldbClient(options);
    await  client.connect();
    const streamRes = await  client.query('list streams;');
    console.log("streams",streamRes);
    await  client.disconnect();
}
```

when I hit that URL from postman am getting below response in node console.

```
Error on Http2 client. Error: connect ETIMEDOUT 16.2XX.X4.xxx:8088
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1159:16) {
  errno: -4039,
  code: 'ETIMEDOUT',
  syscall: 'connect',
  address: '16.2XX.X4.xxx',
  port: 8088
}
```

Comment: https://github.com/Streaminy/ksqldb-client/issues/2
I have created a issue in github source project .

Answer (score 1):

I faced recently with the same issue and found that library has bug with authorization. I pushed PR in repo, but you can patch your local copy in the same way.

https://github.com/Streaminy/ksqldb-client/pull/4